# How to insert an array of UUIDs via JDBC's PreparedStatement into a HyperSQL database

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

Given a table in [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org) with a column of an array of UUIDs, what is the proper way to construct an `INSERT` `PreparedStatement` to populate such a field?

SSCCE:

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // Create UUID array
        UUID[] exmapleArray = new UUID[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < exmapleArray.length; i++){
            exmapleArray[i] = UUID.randomUUID();
        }

        // Load database class
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");

        // Connect to database
        try(Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:foo")){
            try(Statement createStatement = databaseConnection.createStatement()){
                createStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE bar(test_field UUID ARRAY[10])");
            }

            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bar VALUES (?)")){
                // None of the below examples work

                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, databaseConnection.createArrayOf("UUID", exmapleArray));
                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, databaseConnection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", exmapleArray));
                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, databaseConnection.createArrayOf("UUID", Arrays.stream(exmapleArray).map(UUID::toString).toArray()));
                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, databaseConnection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", Arrays.stream(exmapleArray).map(UUID::toString).toArray()));

                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, new JDBCArrayBasic(exmapleArray, Type.BINARY_UUID));
                // preparedStatement.setArray(1, new JDBCArrayBasic(Arrays.stream(exmapleArray).map(UUID::toString).toArray(), Type.BINARY_UUID));

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst populating a plain `UUID` can be done with `PreparedStatement.setString()` populating an array however does not seem to work, yielding several different exceptions depending on the choice of statement above, the most common being:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createArrayOf(Unknown Source)
    at Example.main(Example.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.convertToDefaultType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.convertJavaToSQL(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

The latter two of the commented-out attempts uses HSQLDB-specific classes (specifically `JDBCArrayBasic`) which similarly yields `incompatible data type in conversion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest o use a loop to populate your PreparedStetement, to [insert an array](http://hsqldb.org/web/howToArrays.html) you have to use for example :

```
INSERT INTO bar VALUES ARRAY[3.45, 23.64, 14.01]
```

So to fill your array you have to use a loop like this :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO bar VALUES ARRAY[";
String del = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    query += del+"?" ;
    del = ",";
}
query += "]";
System.out.println(query);
```

your query until now look like this :

```
INSERT INTO bar VALUES ARRAY[?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
```

and you can complete like this :

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(i, "valu_"+i);
}
System.out.println("Query = " + preparedStatement.toString());
```

so in the end your preparedStetement look like this for example :

```
INSERT INTO bar VALUES ARRAY['valu_1','valu_2','valu_3','valu_4','valu_5','valu_6','valu_7','valu_8','valu_9','valu_10']
```

Hope this can gives you an idea.